# Getting lot of Memory leak on image stream

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-leaks

I am trying to refresh image at particular x seconds and getting memory leak after few minutes.

I am getting the code under

```
try {
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity().getContent());
final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
return bmp;
}
```

Then this is refreshed after certain time:
REFRESH_DELAY = 2000
REFRESH_DELAY_SLOW = 6000

```
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
mThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
mBackgroundTask = mThreadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(mRefreshRunable,0,Connectivity.isConnectedFast(getActivity()) ? Config.REFRESH_DELAY : Config.REFRESH_DELAY_SLOW,
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Logs that I am getting:

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1286K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1296K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1285K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1286K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1285K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 47ms, total 48ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1286K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1285K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 43ms, total 44ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1286K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1285K, 16% free 21943K/26064K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
```

Comment: The log you posted at not errors, but only GC logs.

Comment: sorry for the typing error I am not getting error of any type just a lot of memory freeze. :(